# How to search for French-language movies on IMDB?

Tags: search, imdb

Here's the problem:

I searched for French language feature films with a rating of at least 6, on IMDB (here's the address: http://www.imdb.com/search/title?countries=%C2%B7%C2%B7%C2%B7%C2%A0Common%20Countries%C2%A0%C2%B7%C2%B7%C2%B7&languages=fr&num_votes=3000,&title_type=feature&user_rating=6.0,

Now one of the movies that came up was "The Tourist" with Jolie and Depp. And last time I checked, that's not a "French language movie" even if a tad bit of French is spoken there.  I think the distinction is I don't want a movie where someone at some point says something in French but I want the main language to be French.  How do I search for that?

Answer (score 1):

In your search URL, replace `languages=fr` with `primary_language=fr`.